# Dialogflow with actions-on-google fulfillment: Console can't display multiple reponses (How do I send text response?)

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm using Dialogflow with a fulfillment backend based on `actions-on-google`. Adding Responses using `conv.ask('text')` or `conv.add('text')` seems to work. But when I add multiple responses using `conv.add()`, dialogflow is no longer able to display the responses.

This seems to be due to `actions-on-google` returning `simpleResponse` rather than the required `text` Response. I have no idea what happens behind the scenes in dialogflow, but it seems to convert single responses into the required `text` format, but fails to do so for multiple responses. Nothing as such is documented anywhere so I'm just guessing.

Is there a way to send `text` Responses using the `conv` object directly? Or is something else the problem? Documentation on Google's side would really help.

Comment: To be clear - are you writing an Action? Or something that can be used with both the Assistant as well as other integrations? (Where are you expecting to see the `text` response?)

Comment: You should use the actions on Google simulator if building an action

Comment: I'm not building an action, I want to build simple dialogflow fulfillment. I'm using the actions-on-google package because the dialogflow-fulfillment package is almost 2 years old and has practically no documentation

Comment: `actions-on-google` is a library which is built specifically for Google Assistant. It's response format works only on Google Assistant with full functionality. If you build your agent for different platform, you should use its library or Dialogflow's own library so your response JSON will be recognized by other sources. Also, if you need to add multiple response, you can try to add all of them in a string and respond in one function. As far as I know, dialogflow supports only 2 response in one intent.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll have to live with that or code my own library. Because dialogflow's own library hasn't seen a commit for almost a year, with missing features and bugs all over the place. It's built on top of actions-on-google anyway, so I don't see the need for that library (it also doesn't support multiple responses).  Meh.